# to evaluate using L'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anyone please guide me how to  use L'Hop rule to evaluate this

$$
f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds
$$

Comment: New to this concept you see

Comment: Please put this question off hold , you cansee my other questions i post attempt whenever i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds$$
Using L'Hospital rule:
$$
=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds\right)}{\frac{d}{dt}(2t)}$$
Using Extended-Leibniz Rule:$$
f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\frac{\partial( s f'(s))}{\partial t} ds+(x+t)f'(x+t)\frac{\partial(x+t)}{\partial t}-(x-t)f'(x-t)\frac{\partial(x-t)}{\partial t}}{2}\\f(x)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(x+t)f'(x+t)+(x-t)f'(x-t)}{2}\\f(x)=2f'(x)$$
Or:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac12\implies \ln f(x)=\frac{x}2+c\implies f(x)=ke^{x/2}$$

---

For the Extended-Leibniz rule:
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}f(x,\theta)dx\right)=\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}\frac{\partial f(x,\theta)}{\partial\theta}dx+f(b(\theta),\theta).\frac{\partial b(\theta)}{\partial\theta}-f(a(\theta),\theta).\frac{\partial a(\theta)}{\partial\theta}$$

Comment: Can you give any reference for extended leibnitz rule

Comment: @godonichia wikipedia?

Comment: No need for the extended Leibniz rule here.

Comment: Doesn't that rule works when we have  0 as lower bound or both upper and lower bound ss function of x

Comment: @godonichia added to the answer.

Comment: @ADG thatis what i am saying after seeing wiki that bounds are function of theta only , as you wrote .but here they involve t also along with x

Comment: @godonichia no worries, you have to treat x as constant and differentiate the limits wrt theta only

Comment: @godonichia the sign $\partial/\partial\theta$ means "differentiate wrt theta keeping evreything else constant"

Comment: @ADG i am using your rule for a similar question which have same integrand but with x as lower bound and x + t as upper bound and i am getting zero ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19716/discussion-between-adg-and-godonichia).

Answer (score 7):

Think of the integral $$\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)ds = \int_{x-t}^x sf'(s)ds + \int_x^{x+t} sf'(s)ds$$
and now use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate each of these with respect to $t$.

If you're not sure how to do the first one, remember that $\displaystyle\int_{x-t}^x sf'(s)ds=-\displaystyle\int_x^{x-t} sf'(s)ds$.

Comment: Why does most every one appeal to the usual sledgehammer here, instead of taking the more edifying approach in this answer?

Comment: @DavidMitra seems like everyone's choice?

Comment: @DavidMitra can you pleae elaborate

Comment: @godonichia You could use the general rule mentioned by others; but I doubt that's the intended solution. Just use the elementary arguments presented here (in fact, this is easier).

Comment: @DavidMitra actually the OP insisted to use L'HOP

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule, or, as I prefer, the definition of the derivative as a limit, is still required. @ADG